# script.google.com error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I am trying to use a form submit to automatically complete a google doc template I have created. But I keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined, I am a complete newbie, can someone help me please?

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var EmailAddress = e.values[1];
  var CallReportWriter = e.values[2];
  var DateOfMeeting = e.values[3];
  var NameOfTheCustomerProspect  = e.values[4];
  var ContactNameFromClient = e.values[5];
  var TitleandContacts = e.values[6];
  var PresentfromSesomo = e.values[7];
  var MeetingObjectives = e.values[8];
  var MeetingResult = e.values[9];
  var Background = e.values[10];  
  var Opportunities = e.values[11];  
  var Followuprequired = e.values[12];  
  var Responsible = e.values[13];  
  var Targetdates = e.values[14];  


  
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('12zJTxLgy_Nmxk1FScyZ3vqHzYnKQ55ckdQ8RsYy-MdA'); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1SorfCjOGknFVt1ch39MJ7atBorLf_Sdr')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(DateOfMeeting + ',' + NameOfTheCustomer/Prospect, CallReport); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{MeetingDate}}', DateOfMeeting); 
  body.replaceText('{{NameOfCustomer}}', NameOfTheCustomer/Prospect);  
  body.replaceText('{{ReportWriterName}}', CallReportWriter); 
  body.replaceText('{{ContactNameFromClient}}', ContactNameFromClient); 
  body.replaceText('{{TitleAndContact}}', TitleandContacts); 
  body.replaceText('{{PresentFromSesomo}}', PresentfromSesomo); 
  body.replaceText('{{MeetingObjectives}}', MeetingObjectives); 
  body.replaceText('{{MeetingResults}}', MeetingResult); 
  body.replaceText('{{Background}}', Background); 
  body.replaceText('{{Opportunities}}', Opportunities); 
  body.replaceText('{{FollowUpRequired}}', Followuprequired); 
  body.replaceText('{{Responsible}}', Responsible); 
  body.replaceText('{{TargetDate}}', Targetdates); 
  
  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Comment: Kindly [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas) and provide debugging details.

Comment: I hope you not trying to run it from the script editor because that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Open the script editor of the sheet where the form response is landing

```
//
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var resp = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1, e.range.rowStart,14 ).getValues();

  var timestamp = resp[0][0];
  var EmailAddress = resp[0][1];
  var CallReportWriter = resp[0][2];
  var DateOfMeeting = resp[0][3];

// continue your code - I have not tested it


}
```

In script editor, you have to install the on-form-submit trigger

Then as soon as form response lands, your code will run and do whatever you want.